# Angular.ui Modal doesn't close or cancel

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I can't find the way to title this question so if you can suggest a better way, please let me know. Anyway, on to my problem(s).

I am implementing a modal when a user wants to log out. User clicks on the logout icon. The icon invokes the modal with a logout function in my controller like this:

```
<li ng-controller="modalController">
     <a href="" class="mb-control" ng-click="logout();" ><span class="fa fa-sign-out"></span></a>
</li>
```

My **modalController** looks like this

```
app.controller('modalController', ['$scope', '$location', '$uibModal', '$log', function($scope, $location, $uibModal, $log, $uibModalInstance) {
    $scope.logout = function(){
        $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'views/partials/logoutMsg.html'
        });

        $scope.ok = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.close();
            $location.path('/login');
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
        };
    };
}]);
```

And my modal template has this in it:

```
<div class="mb-container">
    <div class="mb-middle">
        <div class="mb-title"><span class="fa fa-sign-out"></span> Log <strong>Out</strong> ?</div>
        <div class="mb-content">
            <p>Are you sure you want to log out?</p>
            <p>Press No if you want to continue work. Press Yes to logout current user.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-footer">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-primary mb-control-close" ng-click="cancel()">No</button>
                <button ng-click="ok()" class="btn btn-success">Yes</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

p.s. My reference calls to Angular bootstrap and my controller in my index.html checks out. And I am including ui.bootstrap in my angular.module as well. Actually, there is no errors in my console indicating any missing dependencies or bad injections.

**THE PROBLEM**

1. The modal does open, but it doesn't close when I click the buttons or outside the modal area. Not only I want it to go away, but the `Yes` button should re-direct to the /login page and the modal dismisses. The `No` button just dismisses the modal. Clicking outside the modal area dismisses the modal as well.
2. The modal is opening over and over and over for as many times as I click the logout icon. It's great that it opens it, but once is sufficient thank you lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things in your code that don't work.

Let's start with the most important thing : *why the modal is not closing ?*.

Your `ok` and `cancel` methods are assigned to a `modalController` scope, but you are not passing any scope to your modal, so it's using `$rootScope` and it doesn't have `ok` and `close` methods. To fix this you have to pass a scope to `$uibModal.open` method, so it should look like this :

```
$uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'views/partials/logoutMsg.html',
    scope: $scope //using modalController scope
 });
```

But this doesn't solve the problem. In `ok` and `cancel` your are referring to `$uibModalInstance` but it's `undefined`. You might think that just injecting it to a controller will solve the problem, but it won't. It's not available to inject - it would be if you'd inject it to a controller in the modal, so to fix this you need to assign the result of `$uibModal.open` to a variable.

```
var $uibModalInstance = $uibModal.open();
```

Here is working solution

https://jsfiddle.net/zho5k7af/

However I'd add a controller to a modal, so you are not polluting `$scope`. See my solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/3dhubhrm/1/

Comment: Excellent solution! thanks! Angular is so young, there really isn't that much help out there, other than the basic stuff. Any idea as to how to stop the icon from invoking the modal once it's already opened? It's not happening in your fiddle, but it is happening for me

Comment: OK, I found that to stop the background from producing more modal calls, it must be disabled by adding 'modal: true,' in function as well. And making sure no items's z-index are higher than the modal's, especially the one with the icon responsible for making the modal call.